# TFS(2015) to GIT migration with history & branches

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, migration, git-tfs

I am trying to migrate a TFS team project under team project collection to GIT version control. My requirement is to move the history & the branch as it is in TFS. I am able to move history but not the branches. The branches are getting created as folders, but i want it as branches in GIT also. Our TFS version is 2015. Below are the commands i used.

```
git tfs clone https://net.com:50443/tfs/Collection "$/Project" --branches=all

git remote add TestRepo https://net.com:50443/tfs/Collection/_git/TestGit

git push -u TestRepo --all
```

Can someone suggest the right way of getting the branches in GIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cloned too high in the TFS path (like git-tfs warned you)...

Instead of cloning "$/Project", you should clone the main branch which should look like something like "$/Project/myMainBranch"... and pray that your TFVC history is entirely supported by git-tfs!